# Is good-sounding a valid adjective?

Tags: adjectives

I'm a high school student from China. My English teacher likes to use adjectives like "good-sounding, nice-looking" etc. like this: "This is a nice-looking hat", "This is a good-sounding music", "Obama is a good-looking man",  "There was a wise-saying sentence". Is such usage corrective?

Comment: _Good-looking_ is certainly idiomatic English, _nice-looking_ is acceptable in colloquial speech, but _good-sounding_ and _wise-saying_ are not.

Comment: You see compounds like "good-sounding" and "bad-sounding" particularly in music and hifi/audio publications. Less formal English does this a lot with sensory words like "happy-sounding", "ugly-sounding", "bad-smelling", etc. Is there a reason that you don't think it's correct? (Although in Chinese English this may be influenced by Chinese, because Chinese lets you combine a lot of elements with 好 (good) to get adjectival expressions.)

Comment: The hyphens between your words are not needed, *good looking* means *good-looking*.

Comment: Hello, Daniel. Look up 'corrective' and see whether it should be 'correct'. // It's best to check on (candidate?) compounds such as these. Though one would expect a general rule, such attempts as 'outstanding-sounding' and 'par-sounding' sound unnatural to  outlandish.

Comment: I hope your teacher doesn't say "This is **a** good-sounding music", because *music* is an uncountable noun and should not take an article.

Answer (score 2):

It's certainly a valid compound adjective and you'll find it used in English publications,  but I'm not sure it is idiomatic with regard to expressing an opinion about a piece of music.

As a musician, it seems idiomatic to me to say that an instrument or a piece of recording equipment is "good-sounding". I might also say that a piece of recorded music was "good-sounding" if I was commenting on its production, that is the way the recording process has captured the music. But I don't think that I, or many other English speakers, would use the expression to mean that they liked a piece of music. It seems very vague and doesn't really say much. Saying a piece of music *is* good (or great, or amazing) expresses a real opinion; saying it "sounds" good is a bit more distant. Saying a movie "sounds good" means you have only heard *about* it, not actually seen it to know it is good.

Looking at results on Google, I also see "good-sounding" used for things that sound *right*, for example, "I got some good-sounding answers".